# Why EC-2 machine is unable to connect into internet if it is behind a Nat Gateway that is associated with a Subnet?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

I try to implement this network in amazon AWS:

[image: Network]

Therefore, I have the following subnets in amazon VPC:

[image: Subnets]

The subnet `subnet-0ac620105fc198e33` uses a NAT Gateway with an elastic IP having the following route table:

[image: Route table]

The `nat-0de30b43c561c4161` is my nat gateway.

The others subnets 2 use the default route table:
[image: Default route table]

And all subnets have the following ACL

[image]

The same rules shown above are applied to inbound and outbound traffic.

I also, have 2 EC-2 instances:

1. That is located in a public subnet used for ssh access in the ones that are in the subnet using the NAT gateway
2. One inthe subnet using the nat gateway

After having access to the second EC-2 instance, I run the following command:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
curl http://google.com
```

But fails to connect into google. Why I am unable to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: the NAT gateway must be in a public subnet, and it must have a route to an internet gateway. AWS documentation covers this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-no-internet-connection).

Look that nat gateway is in a subnet that is accessed through a normal internet gateway in your case both Host1 and Nat Gateway can be in the same subnet or in a subnet that forwards the traffic through a normal internet gateway.

In a simple image what you must achieve is the following:

[image: How network should be]

So consider Nat Gateway as another host that forwards traffic to a subnet that has internet gateway. The diagram above shows how each machine should be connected to internet. In your case `Host 2` accesses `Subnet 2` and through Nat Gatewaty and subnet 1 via a normal Internet gateway accesses the Internet.

In your case, either the subnets `subnet-0c8192051e2a46965` or `subnet-065ae3de09e9f8355` are suitable to host the Nat Gateway. But Nat Gateway must NOT be in the subnet `subnet-0ac620105fc198e33`

In order to change the subnet of the Nat Gateway you must create a new one Nat Gateway afterwards update the route table to utilize the Nat gateway. If you want to keep the Elastic IP wait for the old Nat Gateway to be deleted. Afterwards, use the new one.

And remember once you are creating the new Nat Gateway in this field as shown bellow:

[image]

Select either the subnets `subnet-0c8192051e2a46965` or `subnet-065ae3de09e9f8355`.

Comment: Your question and answer are somewhat confusing. Is your conclusion basically "the NAT gateway must be in a public subnet"?

Comment: Yes Nat gateways must be in a public subnet.

Comment: I've added a summary at the top of your answer. Your diagrams might be easier for people to understand if you show instances / gateways inside subnets rather than pointing to them, as that is a more standard way they're drawn. I suggest you label your subnets public / private as well.

Comment: Well AWS has one but I had hard time to understand them. I find rather easier to place paths towards internet.

Comment: You might benefit from doing the AWS associate architect training. AWS is a complex enterprise system, people generally need training to understand it.